# fancyhdr alternative in beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, header-footer, fancyhdr

I know that it's bad to use fancyhdr together with beamer, so is there something like in alternative?
Would it be possible to achieve this exact same thing, so that I have an image aligned to to left, a centered text (multiline) and a text on the right?

[image: Results with fancyhdr]

Answer (score 2):

Basically you have to change the headline by `\setbeamertemplate{headline}{}`.

Here is a MWE as an entry point.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{adjustbox, graphicx}

% define adjustable rule that fills left space
\makeatletter
   \def\vhrulefill#1{\leavevmode\leaders\hrule\@height#1\hfill \kern\z@}
\makeatother

% change headline
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=1em, wd=\textwidth]{headline}
  \adjustbox{minipage=0.1\textwidth, valign=b}{\inserttitlegraphic \hfill}\hfill
  \adjustbox{minipage=0.7\textwidth, valign=b}{\centering \textbf{\inserttitle}\par \insertauthor\par} \hfill
  \adjustbox{width={0.1\textwidth}, valign=b}{\hfill \insertsubtitle} \par \vspace{-0.25em}
  \vhrulefill{0.25pt}
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
% define title, subtitle, author and titlegraphic
\title{Graphen}
\subtitle{Informatik 11}
\author{Elia}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-a}}

% test
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Frametitle}
Testframe
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Although `beamer` discourages the use of `fancyhdr`, it is actually possible to use it if you take some precautions:

1. You have to set the value of `\headheight` and/or `\footskip` to a value that is large enough (see the warning in your log file for the required values. If no warning then you can skip this.
2. Add this line after setting `fancyhdr` and possible `\headheight`:

   \setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{\headheight}}

Here is a working example.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\fancyhead[L]{\includegraphics[width=0.1\textwidth]{example-image}}
\fancyhead[R]{Informatik 11}
\fancyhead[C]{\textbf{Graphen}\\Elia}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\setlength{\headheight}{30pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{14pt}
\setbeamertemplate{headline}{\vspace{\headheight}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Title}
Test
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]